# Error inserting torch tensors into a heapq using duplicated priorities

Tags: python, torch, heapq

How to avoid `RuntimeError: bool value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous` in this code?

```
import torch
import heapq

h = []
heapq.heappush(h, (1, torch.Tensor([[1,2]])))
heapq.heappush(h, (1, torch.Tensor([[3,4]])))
```

It happens because the comparison between tuples compares the second elements when the first ones are equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to prevent the heapq from trying to compare the second elements of the tuple when it finds duplicate priorities and only needs to redefine the `<` operator for my elements.

```
import torch
import heapq

class HeapItem:
    def __init__(self, p, t):
        self.p = p
        self.t = t

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.p < other.p

h = []
heapq.heappush(h, HeapItem(1, torch.Tensor([[1,2]])))
heapq.heappush(h, HeapItem(1, torch.Tensor([[3,4]])))
```